# How to fix Self-referral issue in Google Analytics 4(GA4)?

Tags: google-analytics, report, google-analytics-4, referrer

I am having an issue with self-referral.
Most of the referrals are being shown as our website.

1. What could be the reason for self-referral still showing even after adding the website url to 'unwanted referrals'? (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10327750?hl=en)
2. What could be the reason for page_referrer not being reported?

I added our website to the list of unwanted referrals, but our website is still being shown as a referral.

Please let me know if there could be any possible causes.